# Google Spreadsheet - Compare multiple pairs of columns to validate data

Tags: filter, google-apps-script, match, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a Google sheet that has two sets of six columns each.
Each set is imported with the `importrange` function from two different spreadsheets that are fed by their own Google webforms.
What I've trying to do without success is to compare at once multiple "pairs" of columns for matching cell contents.
Here goes the example with working data:

**Paid on behalf of customers**

```
Address              Person            Service      Invoice#   $$    Payment date
50 Rodeo Drive       Elton John        Water        10        100   9/07/2013
678 California St    Robert DeNiro     Electricity  15        120   10/07/2013
345 Dalton Rd        Sylvester Stall1  Cable TV     23        45    11/07/2013
9876 Knoxville St    Al Pacino         Water        42        98    12/07/2013
```

**Recovered from customers**

```
Address             Person             Service      Invoice #   $$     Payment date
50 Rodeo Drive      Elton John         Water        10          100    9/07/2013
678 California St   Robert De Niro     Electricity  15          120    10/07/2013
```

My question is **How to compare each pair of columns** altogether (i.e. column "Address" in the first dataset with the column "Address" in the second dataset, and so forth. The aim is to get a third dataset with "only" the recovered invoices, displaying the related data as well (person name, service paid and recovered, invoice #, amount payed and payment date. Is there a *formula/function/google apps script* or a combination of them to perform this task?
I tested with `=ArrayFormula(if(len(D3:D);if(isnumber(match(D3:D;K3:K;0));"Recovered";"Pending");iferror(1/0)))` 
but I can only check if there's a match between two columns and show a flag. I mean, I want to check if there are multiple matches before showing a result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to add a condition to the formula presented by **@DavidTew** `=filter(Paid!A:E, countif(Recovered!A:A&Recovered!B:B&Recovered!D:D,     Paid!A:A&Paid!B:B&Paid!D:D))` that, after filtering the desired range for matches, also writes "X" and "Y" according to the statuses of "match" and "no match"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
=filter(Paid!A:F, countif(Recovered!A:A,Paid!A:A))
```

This will filter the Paid list to show only those entries that are both on the Paid list and the Recovered list (possibly more than once) matching only one column, in this case column A of both.

If you need to filter upon more than one column, you can try something like:

```
=filter(Paid!A:E, countif(Recovered!A:A&Recovered!B:B&Recovered!D:D,     Paid!A:A&Paid!B:B&Paid!D:D))
```

Comment: *@David Tew*: Thanks David, this works perfect! It checks all columns sorting them for items classes. I tried to add a condition so as it also displays a "Recovered" or "Pending" category whenever an item is successfully found in the two sets of columns.